# Compute sift at custom key points

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, sift

I want to find the sift descriptors at custom Keypoint locations in matlab. Is there any function in vlfeat library to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See the [custom frames](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html#tut.sift.custom) section of VLFeat tutorial:

> [...] vl_sift [...] can bypass the detector and compute the descriptor on custom frames using the Frames option.
>
> For instance, we can compute the descriptor of a SIFT frame centered at position `(100,100)`, of scale `10` and orientation `-pi/8` by:

```
fc = [100;100;10;-pi/8] ;
[f,d] = vl_sift(I,'frames',fc) ;
```